# Help on SlimTune Profiler for .NET, how to profile a console application?

Tags: .net, profiling, slimtune

I'm trying to profile a .NET console application with slim tune, but I can't achieved make it working.
I can't find any tutorial on internet, so I hope someone has already used it.

This is what I've done :

1. Build my console app on VS.
2. Open slimtune profiler
3. Click on run
4. Choose "CLR Application (ms .net 2.0, 4.0)" target application type
5. Select my executable (this is a vshost.exe)
6. Set "allow method inlining" to true
7. Select sqlite in-memory
8. Choose for try "Function details" visualizer
9. Click on run
10. A window open, but status is stopped and nothing is profiling

What am I doing wrong ? It should be very easy, but i'm stuck ...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in fact, it looks like that with a real exe (not vshost.exe) it's working